# Is There A Way To Display Intellisence Comments On Implemented Interface Methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio, comments

This is a question about XML comments in Visual Studio.

I have a class that implements an interface. When I place XML comments on the methods that implement the interface, the XML comments in intellisence use the methods from the interface and not the implemented methods. If I remove the comments from the interface methods, intellisence doesn't show any comments. Is there some way to get intellisence to use the comments from the implemented methods instead of the interface methods?

Comment: The point of an interface is that you don't know what implementation it is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way. You should have variable of implementor type to see comments from implemented members.

Consider following. You have interface

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns animal weight
    /// </summary>
    int Weight { get; }
}
```

And you have two implementors - `Dog` and `Cat`. Each has it's own comments for `Weight` property. And you have factory method which returns `IAnimal` instance based on some conditions (i.e. stars in sky)

```
 IAnimal animal = GetAnimal();
```

What do you expect to see on `animal.Weight`? Comments of dog or cat's comments?

Comment: If I implemented the interface, I would expect to see the comments from the implemented methods because the interface is nothing more than a cookie cutter for the classes that implement it. All I care about is the implemented code and how it's used.

Comment: I think maybe the OP's point was that if he doesn't supply comments for `Dog.Weight` or `Cat.Weight` the comment for `IAnimal.Weight` isn't just assumed as a substitute by intellisense.